# Component style not being applied in production -Vue

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have a component `IndexHero.vue` that has a scoped style applied to it

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid>
        <div id="tsparticles" class="particles"></div> 
        
        <v-container 
        fill-height 
        class='mt-n16 fullheight pa-0' 
        >
            <v-row justify="center">
                <v-col cols='12' align='center'>
                    <h1 class=" mt-n16 display-1 font-weight-black">
                    HEADING
                </h1>
            </v-col>
            </v-row>
            
        </v-container>

    </v-container>
</template>

<style scoped>
    .particles {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        border: 2px dashed #f00;
    }
</style>
```

This works fine while I'm in development `npm run dev` but when I generate the static build `npm run generate` the class name is there on the element but the class just isn't there.

I've seen other posts like this use `::v-deep particles` and `* >>> particles` but that has not been successful for me. I've also tried removing scoped but that didn't work either. Can anyone point me in the direction of getting the style applied? Also I'm using Nuxt v2.14.4

Update:
How it shows up in the DOM tree. The `canvas` element is inserted by a JS library `tsparticles` just btw.
[image: dom tree]
[image: dev tools]

nuxt.config.js

```
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

import {fireDb} from './plugins/firebase';


export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  target: 'static',
  components: true,
  render: {
    fallback: false
 },

  //If you're debugging firebase cloud messaging notifications, comment off lines 10 and 11
  //Those two lines exposes the Nuxt dev server on an IP so multiple devices can connect
  //And debug across platforms/screen sizes
  server: {     
    port: 8000, // default: 3000     
    host: '0.0.0.0', // default: localhost   
  }, 

  /*

  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
  
    title: 'COVID-19 in Trinidad and Tobago',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: "Information on this website is not real please do not use or take into consideration.This is the developer site for CoronavirusInfoTT." },
      { hid: 'theme-color', name: 'theme-color', content: '#121212'},

      //Apple Related Tags
      { hid: 'apple-mobile-web-app-title', name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-title', content: 'CoronavirusInfoTT - Developer'},
      { hid: 'apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style', name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style', content: 'black-translucent'},
 
      //Facebook Open Graph Tags
      { hid: 'og:url', property: 'og:url', content: 'https://developer.coronavirustt.info/'},
      { hid: 'og:title', property: 'og:title', content: 'CoronavirusInfoTT - Developer'},
      { hid: 'og:description', property: 'og:description', content: "Information on this website is not real please do not use or take into consideration.This is the developer site for CoronavirusInfoTT."},
      { hid: 'og:site_name', property: 'og:site_name', content: 'developer.coronavirustt.info/'},
      { hid: 'og:image', property: 'og:image', content: 'https://developer.coronavirustt.info/tagimageversiontwo.png'},
      { hid: 'og:image:type', property: 'og:image:type', content: 'image/png'},
      { hid: 'og:image:height', property: 'og:image:height', content: '800'},
      { hid: 'og:image:width', property: 'og:image:width', content: '800'},
      { hid: 'og:image:alt', property: 'og:image:alt', content: 'A preview of the landing page'},
      { hid: 'og:type', property: 'og:type', content: 'website'},


      

      //Twitter tags
      { hid: 'twitter:card', name: 'twitter:type', content: 'summary_large_image'},
      { hid: 'twitter:url', name: 'twitter:url', content: 'https://developer.coronavirustt.info/'},
      { hid: 'twitter:title', name: 'twitter:title', content: 'CoronavirusInfoTT- Developer'},
      { hid: 'twitter:description', name: 'twitter:description', content: "Information on this website is not real please do not use or take into consideration.This is the developer site for CoronavirusInfoTT."},
      { hid: 'twitter:image', name: 'twitter:image', content: 'https://developer.coronavirustt.info/tagimageversiontwo.png'},
      { hid: 'twitter:image:alt', name: 'twitter:image:alt', content: 'A preview of the landing page for the website'},
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      //{ rel: 'preload', as:'style', href: '../node_modules/@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css' },
    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  //loading: '@/components/WanderingCubes',
  /* 
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
    'typeface-roboto/index.css',
    '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css',
    '@/assets/main.css',
  ],
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
    '@/plugins/firebase.js',
  
  ],

  /*
  ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
  */
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
    '@nuxt/components',
  ],

  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxtjs/sitemap',
  ],
  pwa: {
    icon:{
      sizes: [64, 120, 144, 152, 192, 384,512], 
    },
    manifest:{
      name: 'CoronavirusInfoTT',
      short_name: 'COVID-19TT',
      description: "Statistics and information about the COVID-19 virus in Trinidad and Tobago. See visualizations about the virus' activity regarding the number of cases, deaths and recoveries as well as reopening phases. It also acts as a hub for updates from the relevant authorities",
      lang: 'en',
      background_color: '#121212',
    }
  },

 
  
  sitemap: {
    hostname: 'https://coronavirustt.info',
    gzip: true,
    exclude: [
      '/adminlogin',
      '/admindashboard',
    ],
  },

  /*
  ** vuetify module configuration
  ** https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module
  */
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    defaultAssets:false,
    //treeShake: true,
    theme: {
      dark: true,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        }
      }
    }
  },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */


  build: {
   
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
   extend (config, {isClient}) {
      
    if (isClient){
      config.optimization.splitChunks.maxSize = 200500;
    }
  } 
    */


  },

  generate:{
    //fallback: false,
    async routes(){
      
      const qs = await fireDb.collection('covid19tt/initiatives/initiatives').get();
      let d =  qs.docs.map(function(x){
            
            let title = x.data().title;
         
            if(title !== undefined){
              title = title.toLowerCase().replace("'",'').replace(/ /g,'-');
              let date = String( x.data().dateAdded);
              let data = x.data();
              data['dateAdded'] = date;
              data['pageURL']= `https://coronavirustt.info/initiative/${data.urlTitle}/`;
              return {
                route:  `/initiative/${x.data().urlTitle}/`,
                payload: data,
              };
            }else{
              return null;
            }
         
        });
      d = d.filter( f=>{
        if( f !== null) return f;}
      )
      return d;
    }
  },
}
```

Update:
[image]

Comment: @admcfajn I removed the gradients but no joy

Comment: What if you remove all but the most basic styles? does this work? `.particles { height: 100px; width: 100px; border: 2px dashed #f00 }`

Comment: @admcfajn nope. I see a small dashed red box in development but nothing in production still

Comment: open the browser inspector, then check if `div#tsparticles` has css class=`particles`. if yes, check if the properties in class=`particles` are enable or not.

Comment: @Sphinx I don't think it does. I updated my answer to show the elements and styles applied

Comment: @Sphinx I've added the class to a file I have called `main.css` which is loaded in globally. This worked! But throwing in component styles into a global file isn't a good solution but at least it helped me identify that it's a component based issue.

Comment: other scoped css working or not? or only scoped css in this component has this error?

Comment: Please add `nuxt.config.js` &/or `webpack.config.js` that might help get to the root of the problem

Comment: @Sphinx I'm in the process of refactoring so this is the first component. Previously I just had all the content in one page.

Comment: @admcfajn added nuxt.config.js

Comment: if you inspect the generated CSS, do you see the style? maybe it's there but with the wrong `data-v-` selector? just thinking of ways to debug this

Comment: @arieljuod there's no style. I searched the generated CSS. I updated the question

Comment: The selector in your css is `.particles`, not `#tsparticles`, you won't find the style looking for that string. Also, use ctrl+shift+f to search across all resources using devtools.

Comment: @arieljuod apologies I was still trying out things on my end and decided to use the id as the selector for the style. Which worked in development but not in prod. Dev Tools showed two results. One buried in a ton of JS and the same result as in the photo above

Answer (score 2):

I've worked with TsParticles before and it can be problematic sometimes.

You can check my working example on [github](https://github.com/GoulartNogueira/readmystar) of TsParticles on Vue.js / Nuxt.js.

```
 <div id="tsparticles" class="particles"></div>
```

Based on my own previous strugles, I suggest you to rename your id to something different from `tsparticles`, as the names can collide on javascript (it happened to me).